# struct - Partial initialize skipping middle components

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, partial

Suppose I have a `struct` with the following form

```
struct one {
    double d;
    char c1;
    char c2;
    int i;
};
```

I know I can do a partial initialization like this

```
one s1={2.71,'e'};
```

Declaring the values of the first two components only, and leaving the other two blanks. However, what if I want to initialize only the last two components of another `one` `struct`? Am I forced to write

```
one s2={0.0,'\0','a',42};
```

or is there a way I can give instructions about `c2` and `i` only, leaving `NULL` inizializations of `d` and `c1` up to the compiler?

Comment: "*and leaving the other two blanks.*" All members are getting initialized. The last two get zero-initialized.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's what I meant, sorry for the misuse of terminology. I used "blank" as a synonym of "containing `0`" while it actually means "not containing anything"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you want to to this, however you could define a constructor like:

```
one( char c2Arg, int iArg ) : c2(c2Arg), i(iArg) {}
```

and call it like:

```
one s1('a', 42);
```

Instead of leaving th first two members uninitialized, it is probably better to assign default values to them:

```
one( char c2Arg, int iArg ) : d(0.0), c1('\0'), c2(c2Arg), i(iArg) {}
```

Comment: I understand `struct`s are more of a C thing, and in C++ you almost always use `class`es which have private parts and constructors. However, I'm following a C++ course and it talks about `struct`s before introducing `class`es, and leaves this matter open when explaining partial initialization. I had this purely theoretical doubt I wanted to get rid of, just to better understand the language, even if the matter is hardly practically useful.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski: `structs` do have constructors, just like classes. The only difference is that in a struct, all members are public by default.

Comment: I beg pardon in advance if the question is stupid, but if I want to initialize different elements in different structures of the same type (absurd case, I know, purely theoretical), how can I declare different constructors and use them? Sorry, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski: You can define as many constructors as you want, as long as the numbers or types of their arguments are different. This is called method overloading.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got it.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski Note that the constructor shown here really does leave two members *uninitialized*, meaning it is undefined behaviour to read from them.